# Double Tap makes crash SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, skscene

I am new to `SpriteKit` game dev.
In my game when character touch enemy , it will show game over scene and restart it.

However after Game Over Scene showed, double in game is making app crash.
Here is my codes in MainGameScene.

```
- (void)gameOver
{
    GameOver *over = [[GameOver alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *trans = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:over transition:trans];
}
```

And here is GameOver Scene.

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    self = [super initWithSize:size];
    {
        SKLabelNode *lblGameOver = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        lblGameOver.text = @"Game Over";
        lblGameOver.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        lblGameOver.fontSize = 35;
        lblGameOver.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblGameOver.zPosition = 2;
        [self addChild:lblGameOver];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [super didMoveToView:self.view];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newGame)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)newGame
{
    GameScene * scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *trans = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:scene transition:trans];
}
```

That make crash my app when i double tap in New Game Scene.
Error message is

```
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)
```

How could i fix it?

Comment: It has been a while sense I have played around with tap gestures but my best guess is that you never remove the old tap gesture from the view and it is trying to call a method that is gone. You may need to create a property for that tap gesture and remove it from the view before you present the next scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your didMoveToView method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newGame)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; // 1 for a single tap or 2 for a double tap
```